# VOIP on Android libraries or sample code

Tags: android, voip

Thanks in advance.
I am working on a VOIP application on Android.

Are there any open-source code, libraries or sample applications, for VOIP software developers to quickly create VOIP apps? Thanks in advance.

actually i don't know the process for using **voip** in android app.. so how to use voip in app.

Comment: Sorry but what exactly is your question?  An operating system can't provide code ... A developer can ...

Comment: Oh, sorry for misunderstanding your question then. But I'm not clear what you mean then: the process? Do you have code that implements VOIP or not?

Comment: His question is open ended but what he might be looking for, is how to get started with VOIP / SIP for implementation. From here you can start http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/network/sip.html, but remember there are lots of devices that doesn't support native SIP in android. I myself looking for a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think you probably want the [SIP package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/package-summary.html).