# How to implement realtime voice chat between Android and iOS devices?

Tags: android, ios

We need to implement realtime voice chat between Android and iOS devices.

It's been done in apps like [Viber](http://www.viber.com/).

How should we go about it?

Comment: You will first need a central server which will re-route the voice data to and from your app. Your server will also have to take care of who is or is not online(who the user can call or cannot call).   

The server will simply be sending the received data so it is dealing with socket connections. I don't think it matters here whether the data comes from a iOS device or an Android device.

Comment: @LittleChild, Thanks! Could you recommend a specific server technology that we could use?

Comment: so you want to send a voice data ? or it'll be like a call?

Comment: Google how you can set up a VoIP server. That should help

Comment: @nayoso Send voice over internet. Like Viber. 1 on 1.

Comment: @LittleChild so it will be like a phone call? basically he can use SIP protocol then

Comment: @nayoso **HOW** is the OP's question :) A link to a resource will be awesome. *Even I would love to read about it* :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734519/voip-on-android-libraries-or-sample-code *ba dum tss*

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/package-summary.html

Comment: @LittleChild Ah sorry I will add a new answer as what I did before from my experience before :)

Comment: @nayoso Feel free to edit and improve my answer :)

Comment: @nayoso You cannot write "I have used it" in **my** answer !!! :D That is such a lie! Come on!! LOL

Comment: @LittleChild sorry man :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is SIP

> The Session Initiation Protocol (SIP) is a signaling communications
>   protocol, widely used for controlling multimedia communication
>   sessions such as voice and video calls over Internet Protocol (IP)
>   networks.

Android provides the [`android.net.sip`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/package-summary.html) package which...

> Provides access to Session Initiation Protocol (SIP) functionality,
>   such as making and answering VOIP calls using SIP.

[If you want a demo, please have a look at the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html#manifest)

Original Source: [VOIP on Android libraries or sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734519/voip-on-android-libraries-or-sample-code)

another lib for Android :
https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/
http://www.linphone.org/
http://mjsip.org/mjua.html
http://www.doubango.org/

---

For iOS, you can use [`PJSIP`](http://www.pjsip.org/)

> PJSIP is a free and open source multimedia communication library
>   written in C language implementing standard based protocols such as
>   SIP, SDP, RTP, STUN, TURN, and ICE. It combines signaling protocol
>   (SIP) with rich multimedia framework and NAT traversal functionality
>   into high level API that is portable and suitable for almost any type
>   of systems ranging from desktops, embedded systems, to mobile
>   handsets.

another lib for iOS :
http://www.linphone.org/
http://www.pjsip.org/
http://sofia-sip.sourceforge.net/development.html
http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/exosip/

Original Source: [How to implement VoIP + SIP in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558302/how-to-implement-voip-sip-in-iphone)

Comment: Would this protocol work on iOS devices?

Comment: @EmanuilRusev AFAIK, you will need a SIP server which will re-route the voice data. So, what I pointed out is how you will code the app in Android. Similar functionality will exist in iOS, I am sure

Comment: the topic is closed but we still can put a comment, nice. @LittleChild,... what about if there's no SIP account? I mean, in ad-hoc communication usage, how would it be?

Comment: @gumuruh I am not sure. Maybe create a one-time-use account every time the user logs in? Sorry for the delayed reply